# Colocar elementos lado a lado css/html/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso colocar esses dois elementos um do lado do outro, como posso fazer? Usando html/css/bootstrap.

Meu code:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Html:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="pesquisa">
<form id="filter">
<label>Filtre tickets pelo nome: </label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="termo" name="termo" />
<br>
</form>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
       <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Filtros Adicionais</h3>

        <div class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="btn opcoes" data-toggle="dropdown">Opções<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
              <li><a class="btn ultimos15" (click)="getUltimos15Dia()">Últimos 15 Dias</a></li>
              <li><a class="btn ultimos30" (click)="getUltimos30Dia()">Últimos 30 Dias</a></li>
              <li><a class="btn ultimos60" (click)="getUltimos60Dia()">Últimos 60 Dias</a></li>
              <li><a class="btn visualizartodos" (click)="getTickets()">Visualizar todos os Tickets</a></li>
              <li>  <a class="btn limpaTicketsFechados" (click)="getLimpaTicketsFechados()">Limpar Tickets Fechados
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </a></li>
              <li> <a class="btn visualizaFechados" align="center" (click)="getTicketsLimpados()">Visualizar Tickets Limpados
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
              </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

Css:

```
.pesquisa{
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do bootstrap?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá pra fazer isso só usando o Bootstrap, sem css adicional. Levei em consideração que você está usando a versão 3.3.7 do Bootstrap, mas acredito que, a não ser que você esteja usando alguma versão > 4, não vai dar nada de errado com o código abaixo.

O bootstrap tem um sistema de linhas (rows) e colunas (columns). Tudo que você precisa fazer é criar uma linha e dividir essa linha em duas colunas. Ou seja, uma parte do filtro fica na coluna da esquerda e a outra parte na da direita.

Na prática, o bootstrap tem 12 colunas dentro de um container, então ao invés de reservar uma pra esquerda e uma pra direita, vamos reservar 6 colunas pro filtro da esquerda (col-md-6) e 6 colunas pro filtro da direita (col-md-6) e colocar essas 12 colunas dentro de uma linha (row).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <form id="filter">
        <label>Filtre tickets pelo nome: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="termo" name="termo" />
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Filtros adicionais</label>
      <div class="dropdown">

        <a href="#" class="btn opcoes">
          Opções <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buzrpkmo/1/)